# My friend cosigned for a defaulted loan. Should he declare Chapter 7 bankruptcy?

Tags: united-states, loans, auto-loan, bankruptcy, co-sign

## Background:

My friend Abe co-signed an auto loan for about $25k with his "friend" Bella, in the USA state of Maryland, about 4-5 months ago. The car was for Bella's use. The deal was that Bella would make payments on the car and when it was paid off she would keep the car. All contracts between Abe and Bella were verbal, handshake-only. Bella and Abe are both on the title *application*, with Bella as the primary. The paperwork was completed and sent to the Maryland Motor Vehicle Administration (MVA), the auto loan was approved based on Abe's credit, and the car was driven off by Bella. For reasons I don't understand neither the title, nor the registration, nor permanent plates were ever issued. When Abe asked the Motor Vehicle Administration why, they simply stated there was an "insurance violation" with no further explanation.

Of course, Bella made no payments and the car will soon be assigned for repossession. It appears Bella intends to keep the car until someone takes it away from her. All attempts at reason have failed. She is hiding the car to prevent Abe or the repo man from grabbing it. The only thing left is to wait for the car to get repossessed (hopefully quickly, but Bella is a veteran criminal), sold at auction, and see what the final debt is.

## Question:

Because the car will end up being involuntarily repossessed, Abe will have a black mark on his credit for 7 years, or so I'm told. Abe has about $4k in credit card debt to add to the $10-$15K or more of losses on the car fiasco. He has only about $2k in cash, about $20k in an IRA, probably $2-$3k in equity in his condo, and no other real assets. Should Abe just go into Chapter 7? He'll already have a repo on his credit, how much worse can bankruptcy be?

Abe owns a condo and has always paid his mortgage on-time. He has some money in a retirement IRA. His income is about $40k, of which about $12k is SSA disability. Abe has already accepted that he'll be unable to get any credit for a long time.

Comment: How did the car lose $10-15K in value in just 4-5 months? That would be high ever for heavy driving, and presumably it doesn't have many new miles on it if it was never registered.

Comment: @TTT I find it credible.  It's from the interest, penalties, fees, and considerable repo costs from a car-holder who is evading.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - I wouldn't have thought those costs get passed on to the cosigner. In fact, if the bank repos, I think they would have to give the cosigner first option of paying it off before they send it to auction. So I'm thinking cosigner could sell the car and would only have to come up with the difference, which on a recently purchased car with no new miles, shouldn't be more than a few thousand difference. (Though if they tack on the fees like you suggest, then yeah- that seems like it could be expensive.)

Comment: @TTT Oh, all those costs get passed onto the debtors.  And that's when they find out that the prefix "co-" means "equal/partner" not auxiliary or subordinate... I wonder what throws people on that... the co-pilot having 3 bars instead of 4?  And yes, Abe could step up and buy the car out at any moment (and could make that conditional on a credit report clear). But in Abe's current situation there's no money for that, and then Abe would have the problem of the car being absconded with...

Comment: @TTT: What Harper said. I expect Bella to make the repo man work hard to find the car. In addition, the car will be sold at auction for almost certainly much less than it's worth. Finally, Bella puts many more miles on the car than average, drives insanely aggressively, and I doubt does much if any basic maintenance. She'll probably never get the oil changed. Actually, now that I write that, considering what shape the engine will be in it's possible the car will be sold for more than it's worth at auction. I'll tell Abe the good news.

Comment: *if the bank repos, I think they would have to give the cosigner first option of paying it off before they send it to auction* just to be clear on the order of operations, the bank will come after the cosigner to collect on the debt *before* they repo it. A cosigner is basically treated as "equal but separate" in terms of responsibility for the debt. The lender will pursue both parties, equally, and independently of each other.

Comment: *For reasons I don't understand neither the title, nor the registration, nor permanent plates were ever issued* That's troubling and I wonder if it's even accurate. But I don't know much about how MD handles vehicle registrations and titles. If I were Abe, I would follow up very hard on determining if this is really true, just so things are clear when the stuff hits the fan in terms of what paperwork exists and who's name is on what.

Comment: Did Abe report the car as stolen to the police? If he doesn't know where it is and has a legal right to it, that might be the way to go, voluntarily surrendering it before it gets to repo stage would save some as they are entitled to deduct repo fees from the value they get for the vehicle before applying the difference to what you owe.

Comment: @HartCO: The car is not stolen. Barring a court saying otherwise, both Abe and Bella are equally entitled to the car. Their relative rights to the vehicle seems to be an entirely civil matter, not criminal. If Abe goes to the cops and says Bella stole the car, the cops will look the car up and see that Bella and Abe are on at least the title application. That will be the end of the matter as far as they're concerned.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk My point was that it might get the car located. All Abe knows is that nobody can find the car he jointly owns and Bella is either not talking or doesn't know where the car is either.

Comment: Though it is not germane to the legal situation, I am curious to know what Abe thought he was getting out of this deal; was it just the warm fuzzy feeling of helping out a "friend"?

Comment: @EricLippert: It's a long story, but Abe is what might be called a vulnerable adult. Once Abe trusts someone he trusts them absolutely, and doesn't see the numerous red flags that you or I would. Abe's friends and family will be much more vigilant in the future.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk if that's the case, it might be worth talking to a lawyer to see if there's some way to void the contract. Might be a long shot, but it's worth a try with this amount of money on the line.

Comment: "I think they would have to give the cosigner first option of paying it off before they send it to auction." Yes, absolutely. If Abe pays off the loan, he will avoid repossession, auction, black mark on credit, etc. But if he had the money, he probably wouldn't have gotten the loan in the first place.

Comment: "So I'm thinking cosigner could sell the car and would only have to come up with the difference, which on a recently purchased car with no new miles," Besides the question of whether he'll be able to sell the car with Bella on the title, people don't generally buy a car unless the car is actually present. Since Abe doesn't have physical possession of the car, selling it will be difficult.

Comment: I wonder if a prosecution for elder abuse might be warranted.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: Abe is not old enough to be protected by those laws. Abe is vulnerable, but I don't think he's vulnerable enough meet the definition of ["vulnerable adult"](https://law.justia.com/codes/maryland/2010/criminal-law/title-8/subtitle-8/8-801/), which is the threshold needed to run afoul of [Maryland code § 8-801](https://law.justia.com/codes/maryland/2010/criminal-law/title-8/subtitle-8/8-801/). Abe takes care of his daily needs and has for years.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk Perhaps Abe can consent to some sort of declaration of incompetence/power of attorney, if Abe sees that the current situation is unworkable.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

DON'T talk to the creditor. DON'T trash your other good credit. DON'T declare bankruptcy for a good while.

### The IRA is protected. Protect it.

First and foremost, **the IRA is untouchable** in [MD](https://www.bwfa.com/articles/july-2010/protecting-your-ira-from-creditors-or-lawsuits/).  Creditors cannot touch it.  Bankruptcy cannot touch it. Abe **must not** touch it.  The IRA is a sort of "trust account", and Abe, as a "trustee", must protect that from misspending (by Abe).

The penalty for failing as your own trustee is 10% - and since the money wasn't taxed before, **it's taxed now** both Federal and State. In short, a fool cashing out an IRA in a panic will lose 50% to taxes -- and worse, there won't be withholding, so the 50% will come as a  **Huge Surprise** on April 15 of the next year.

But that is the fate of fools.  Abe must take care not to be one.

### It's not as severe as you think. Don't make it worse.

Right off the bat keep  your other credit relationships tip-top.  Pay all your minimum payments on-time etc. Keep the fire isolated to one place.

Having ONE bad mark from ONE creditor is not the end of the world for your credit report. The 7 years is already counting down because it started at the R9.  And it represents *one* dispute with *one* vendor.   **A bankruptcy is much worse**.  It means a total financial meltdown, and it's 10 years - not from the R9 but the final disposition of the bankruptcy *a year from now*.  So it's really 11 years and hasn't even started yet.

Declaring bankruptcy because of *one* bad mark would be like a gifted chess player losing three games in a row, and then rage-quitting chess.

The one thing bankruptcy will do - and weak minds enjoy this - is make the defaulted creditor bother you less. In theory. And that's no guarantee.  *That's not much of a benefit compared to the heinous cost of it*.  You can throw away their letters *for free*. You can tell them to shag off on the phone, *for free*.  You don't need bankruptcy for that.

*However. Abe is able to effectively use the spectre of bankruptcy like a ["Fleet in being"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleet_in_being), having the very real effect of deterring the creditor on the fear that Abe **always could** declare bankruptcy. Abe gets to use this "chilling effect" to full force.*

### DO NOT TALK TO THE CREDITOR

Nothing good can come of it, and only bad. **They are extremely good at manipulating people**. Say nothing except "stop calling" *And. Hang. Up.*   Anything you say can and will be used against you... well in theory negotiations are excluded, but you have to do everything right to make that happen, and they're really good at tricking you into blowing it.

I get where the creditor call can feel like a scab you just gotta pick.  Don't.

### Oh, but they might sue me!

No, that's not gonna happen.

Assuming you've been candid about Abe's assets, the first thing the creditor will do -- pre-lawsuit -- is do an asset search on Abe.  They're going to see an Abe with virtually no *attachable assets*.

*See, here's the thing.  When you sue someone, it costs typically $5000+, so you better be likely to recover significantly more than that.  And you have to assume the defendant will do everything possible to defend. You might get to the very end of the lawsuit (verdict) and boom! The Defendant declares bankruptcy, undoing all your work! Oh no! So you must plan for that outcome and make sure the defendant has, say, $10,000 of assets **beyond** that which is [protected in bankruptcy by MD law](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/how-to-file-bankruptcy-in-maryland.html).  And MD law protects plenty! $25k of home equity, disability benefits and judgments, insurance payouts, public benefits, IRAs of course, $5000 in clothing, books, and tools of trade, $1000 in appliances, burial plot, and a $6000 wildcard on top of that! **Abe is completely protected.***

*Oh, and legal warchest too.  The court wants you to pay your lawyer, and treats your own lawyer as a priority debt.  It's not like they'll clawback money from your lawyer to pay other creditors, nor would plaintiff's lawyer ask for that (as a professional courtesy)*.

So a lawsuit would be an utterly futile gesture. And they know it. And they won't sue.

### In the meantime, Abe should cut costs and save up.

Leave the IRA alone.  Don't rush to pay down the existing credit card (keep paying minimums on-time, obviously).  Cut costs hard, and save up a cash war-chest. (you should have 6-9 months of emergency fund *anyway*, so this is just a fraction of that).  I'd like to see Abe enter this thing with $5000 ready to go.  That's the price of a clean exit.

In the meantime, Abe needs to get a thick skin about an infinite number of collection calls and letters, **and never say anything except to shag off**.  They will come until below, and that's the cosmic punishment *instead of bankruptcy*.

### Eventually, this happens.

A year or two goes by. Abe gets a lawyer to write up a contract.  It says:

- Abe was the innocent victim of a swindler.
- The creditor gets $5000, in exchange for which, Abe is removed altogether from this matter.
- There is a dispute over whether this is Abe's debt, or not. As such, no negative statements will be made by either party about the other, and in particular, **no negative data will be reported to any credit reporting agency**, with $10,000 liquidated damages for breach.
- Abe never benefited from this debt, and as such, no 1099-C will be filed, nor will any income be reported to any agency.
- Venue, jurisdiction, whole agreement, counterparts, blah blah.

One day, completely out of the blue, this offer shows up on the creditor's doorstep.  **The creditor is going to think they hit the lottery** because up until now, this was a dead-dog uncollectible. They don't care about this other stuff. They care about the payday.  Will they agree to that? *Oh, you betcha.*

You could probably have your lawyer haggle the number down.  Whatever. The "No 1099-C / Clean the Credit Report" is a showstopper, and is good cause to sweeten the deal.

**And Abe is out.  Clean and clear.**

Two months later, check the credit report. **Clean** and **Spiff**.

*It will literally be as if it never happened. Well, except for the $5000, but that will be the ultimate price of the affair.*

### Oh noes! They sued anyway!

Then you declare ...

> ... that they are idiots.  (Did you think I was going to say something else?)

Even if they know about the abovementioned $5000, even if that was somehow unshielded... Abe's lawyer *has dibs on it*.  They can't argue with that.

So get in conference and you say "I'll spend my last dollar hiring my lawyer to make the most vigorous defense possible, bar none.  And then, after verdict, I'll have my lawyer thwart all your collection actions.  If you finally get a garnishment, I'll declare bankruptcy the next day, and all my assets are protected.   **OR, you can go for what's behind door #2**. (and present the contract above).

That will be the end of that lawsuit.

### Then there's the other lawsuit...

Abe would have a right-of-action against Bella, on two prongs.  First, Abe can get a civil court order to hand over the car. (the inverse of a restraining order, compelling rather than prohibiting behavior).  And if Bella refuses, the judge has the option to jail Bella indefinitely for civil contempt of court (which is a sanction, not a crime).

Second, Abe has the right to recover all losses and costs.  However, all the friction we discussed above that protects Abe from creditors, has the same effect to protect Bella from Abe getting a useable recovery.  So Bella would have to achieve some level of wealth before that target would have any fruit.  Presumably that is not the case, if Bella is using romance to swindle cars.

Abe would have to *file* the suit before the relevant statute of limitations, but could spend some additional time trolling out the actual litigation, and then would have 10 years to collect, which is renewable.  For what it's worth: If Abe can prove fraud/crime was involved, then Bella cannot wash this debt away in bankruptcy.

Comment: This seems very wise. Save bankruptcy as a last resort, only to be used if the plan somehow fails and the creditor goes to court and wins. If the creditor is rational they also understand that they won't win any money if a court victory forces Abe into a bankruptcy. I have two questions. You wrote "leave the balance on the credit cards". Did you mean make no payments at all, or make minimum payments? I also wonder, should we make the creditor aware of Abe's complete asset picture? Or is that pointless because they'll always assume Abe is hiding something?

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk - I wanted to emphasize this part of Harper's message: collectors working for lenders are notorious for being relentless and aggressive. They like to play off your emotions, and wear you down. However, they're also practical, and focused on results: they manage their time and efforts according to what will yield the highest recovery. If they know they can't get anything from you, that tends to take the wind out of their sails. Make sure Abe knows not to tell them *anything* and eventually they'll realize he's a dead end (especially as he has no assets) and move on.

Comment: Ask a lawyer for proper phrasing for, "I'll spend my last dollar hiring my lawyer to make the most vigorous defense possible, bar none. And then, after verdict, I'll have my lawyer thwart all your collection actions. " Getting this phrasing wrong may hurt you during a bankruptcy hearing.

Comment: @Brian it better not!! Things said in conference are *privileged*.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk make minimum payments until the $5k cash is built up.  Not paying the minimum will create a new, entirely self-inflicted, black mark on Abe's credit.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: Not being a lawyer, I'm not sure whether privilege applies to communications with your debtor.  Note: This is comment is not an invitation to say whether such privilege applies or does not apply.  It's a warning to future readers to ask a lawyer such questions.

Comment: Great answer, but... does Abe have any recourse against Bella (later) to recover the $5k?

Comment: @Michael Added a section at the end.  You're right, and Abe could use the courts to recover the car as well (or at least make sure Bella ain't driving it).

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk Like I said about "it's only one creditor" and not rage-qutting chess, *yeah, you definitely want to keep your other credit relationships tip-top.*  Abandoning all credit is the mentality of someone who has decided on bankruptcy, and even that thinking is based on myth.  I woudln't voluntarily disclose Abe's credit picture to the creditor *first, because that would involve "talking to the creditor" and that is a mistake!!*  And second they wouldn't  believe it anyway.

Comment: @Brian Collections calls **should be** *pro se* settlement conferences and so **should be** excluded from evidence, but collectors are devious and manipulative. It'll work if the lawyers are in the room.

Comment: -1. This advice is very unethical IMHO. Abe has cosigned a loan, so Abe has a moral obligation to repay at least half the loan. The fact that Bella cheated Abe is not the problem of the creditor: the creditor gave his own precious money only because of Abe's credit score. When cosigning the loan, Abe gave his word that the money will be returned. At the very least, Abe and the creditor should split the loss. Please put yourself at the shoes of the creditor and read the answer again.

Comment: Additionally: from a social perspective, it is important that Abe has a "black mark" on his credit score. He might do the same mistake again and cosign a loan with a second "Bella", and it is important that the future creditors will know that they should not trust this cosigner. If you disagree, then please imagine that you are a future creditor. Would you like to lend money to a person who does not return?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi First, as usual, your morality murders our mutual consent; that the creditor and Abe can't *mutually agree* what's fair, but we need the Nanny ChurchState imposing it.  Second, *Abe's $5000 does not settle the debt*. The creditor still has full and total right to pursue Bella for the FULL amount plus Abe's $5000 too. And I think that plus a year of torture will teach Abe. ***Very** unethical*?? Do you have a sense of scale? Swindler, creditor... And Abe's the "very unethical" one???

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Of course you do not have to agree with me, but here is my reason [and it is unrelated to any church or state..]. The money is gone - Bella cannot be forced to pay it (as you say yourself). There is one criminal here - Bella. There are two innocent people here - Abe and the creditor. So the fairest solution is that they split the loss. Why do you think that the creditor should take most of the loss? What would you say if you were the creditor?

Comment: You forgot the value of the car the creditor *will* get back.  They will probably end up with about $8000 net costs and Abe just paid $5000. What's your problem with that?  Look. You just used my good answer to grandstand, which I don't appreciate none too much, and you're wrongheaded at every level. I know you'll chat about this all night, but that is not the purpose of comments and I don't want the comments section of a good answer hijacked.  So this is my last reply.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi: What do you want of Abe? What exactly is your calculus of ethics and morality here? That Abe is 50% guilty and so should suffer 50% of the pain? And the creditor is completely innocent, even though interest rates charged reflect the fact the creditor is **gambling** that Abe and Bella will repay him? Abe knows he is morally obligated to pay the debt, but financially that isn't possible. This answer provides information that Abe can use to *negotiate* with the creditor and perhaps reach an agreement. And Abe will never again make *any* significant financial decisions alone.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk If you were the creditor, what would you expect Abe to do in this situation?

Comment: The creditor would like Abe to give them all his money, his internal organs, everything. Why does the wants of the creditor matter?